# alsa://hw:1,0 is not accessible before login to KDE (Kubuntu 14.04)

Tags: stream, vlc, kde-plasma, ubuntu

I have an audio stream

```
cvlc -vvv alsa://hw:1,0 --sout '#transcode{acodec=mp3,ab=128}:standard{access=http,mux=ogg,dst=192.168.0.106:8081}'
```

and it works if i logged in KDE, but if i see login window (where you need to type password kde login) i cannot open alsa device.

I got

```
vlc cannot open MRL 'alsa://hw:1,0'.
```

Is it possible to have access to alsa without login to KDE? 
Any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

alsa is KDE independent; before logging in, from a console (ctrl+alt+F1) use this command: `aplay -l`, it will show all audio devices; I think kde has some script to change the soundcard stack

Comment: `--> aplay -l
aplay: device_list:268: не найдено ни одной звуковой карты...
(No cards found)

by runnig this command in sudo i can see cards, but i not able to run cvlc from sudo.

Comment: it seems users don't have permissions on sound card, repeat the same commands (with and without sudo) once you logged in KDE